# How to build a tunnel in A-Train 8?

Tags: a-train-8

How do you make a tunnel in A train 8. I have got the tunnels lined up and at the same elevation but the train refuses to go through. [image]

Comment: need more info, guessing this is in iOS? If so, have a look at these solutions. http://trainyard.ca/solutions

Comment: I have got a tunnel built but it seems to be closed up. the train goes towords it,stops and changes direction. Both tunnel ends are at the same height. Enough info.

Comment: There is an iOS game called Trainyard that I am a huge fan of, but this question makes no sense to me (Trainyard doesn't have tunnels or elevation) so I can only assume you are talking about a different game. Can we have a link or something to establish which game you are asking about?

Comment: I am talking about A train 8 but i cant make a tag for the game. PlZ change tags if you can.